# Como puedo ejecutar mis codigos de Dev-c++ en Visual Studio Code?

Tags: vscode

muy buenas comunidad resulta que he decidido usar este IDE para mis códigos en C, (soy principiante), por lo que migré toda la carpeta de Dev-c++ a este IDE (VSC) pero al querer ejecutar me dice que tengo error en las librerias y que edite el include path pero no se como... he buscado videos y nada... Anexo imagen del problema
de antemano gracias quedo atento !
PD: ya instale los paquetes que te refiere al inicio de la instalación y aun así continua el problema
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

Conseguí compilar código C en VSCode pero no había tenido el tiempo de publicar  la solución, no pretendo tomar méritos que no son míos así que dejo el link de donde saque el método de instalación esperando en apoyar a quien tenga el mismo problema así que bien [aquí se los dejo](https://platzi.com/tutoriales/1189-algoritmos-2017/2765-compilando-cc-desde-visual-studio-code-windows-10/)